# Transfer embed messages between chats discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to transfer a embed message from a channel to another channel using reactions.
I've trying somthing like this:

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (message) => {
    let analiseChannel = message.client.channels.cache.get(analiseChannelID);

    const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get(aprovadasChannelID);
    if (analiseChannel) {
        const { content, embeds } = message
        channel.send({
                content,
                embeds
            }).then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

And this is the error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (R:\@Aplicações\Discord\hylex\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (R:\@Aplicações\Discord\hylex\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (R:\@Aplicações\Discord\hylex\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:15) {
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

*I don't know if the way I'm doing is the better one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event gives an instance of [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) as its first argument. You can destructure the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message) out of it

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", ({ message }) => { //notice the braces around "message"
    let analiseChannel = message.client.channels.cache.get(analiseChannelID);

    const channel = message.client.channels.cache.get(aprovadasChannelID);
    if (analiseChannel) {
        const { content, embeds } = message
        channel.send({
                content,
                embeds
            }).then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

Comment: `RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string.` 
Now I have this error, is that because i'm trying to collect the information from an embed message and send to another chat?

Comment: Try sending it without the `content` property if it has no content (only an embed)

Comment: Do you know how am I supposed to delete the message already transfered to the other chat?